# Как нажать на кнопку через код? python kivy kv

Tags: python, kivy

Хочу что-бы при вводе текста в input окно, нажималась кнопка(сама). Не могу найти как это реализовать.
Мой код: input меняет название кнопки, потом кнопка меняет название label(но ее нужно нажимать самому).

.py

```
class test_but(BoxLayout):

    def testfunc(self):
        pass

    def change_name_lbl(self):
        self.lbl.text = self.bt1.text

    def input_text(self, text):
        text_inp = self.inpt.text

        self.bt1.text = text_inp
class My1App(App):

    def build(self):
        return test_but()
```

.kv

```
<test_but>:


lbl: label1
inpt: input1
bt1: but1

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: "Hellow"
    TextInput:
        id: input1
        on_text:
            root.input_text(self.text)
    Button:
        id: but1
        text: "text_but"
        on_press:
            root.change_name_lbl()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для своей цели вопрос решил. Нужно было при определенном input запустить функцию смены имени label.
Дополненный код .py:

```
class test_but(BoxLayout):

    def testfunc(self):
        pass

    def change_name_lbl(self):
        self.lbl.text = self.bt1.text

    def input_text(self, text):
        text_inp = self.inpt.text

        self.bt1.text = text_inp

    

        if text_inp == "Hellow World":
            self.change_name_lbl()
    


class My1App(App):

    def build(self):
        return test_but()
```